# Examine the uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+nx}$ in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+nx}$ in $(0,1)$. Examine the uniform convergence in $(0,1)$.

My attempt: Here the pointwise limit is $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$.

Now,$$\sup_{x\in (0,1)} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = \sup_{x\in (0,1)} \frac{1}{1+nx}$$If  $x\rightarrow 0^+$, then the sup becomes $1$, hence $f_n \not\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $(0,1)$.

Am I correct?

Comment: That seems perfectly fine yes.

Comment: Indeed, the $\sup$ is equal to $1$ so there is no uniform convergence. Another way to prove that is to see that $f_n(1/n)=1/2$ does not tend to $0$, so the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: You are correct logically, but "If $x\to 0^+$" is a bit hand-wavy. Just take $x=1/n$ to show that  the $\sup\geq\frac12.$

Comment: I mean, the long form of your statement is: "Since $$\lim_{x\to0^+} f_n(x)=1$$ and $f_n(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in(0,1)$ then $\sup f_n(x)=1.$" But even that requires more knowledge about $\sup.$ Picking a specific $x_n=\frac 1n$ alleviates you from talking limits or the exact value of the supremum. You just get a lower bound on the supremum, and that is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. I will just make it preciese.

If it converges uniformly, then there exists $N>0$ such that, for any $n>N$,
$$\sup_{x\in (0,1)}\frac{1}{1+nx}<1/2$$

Let $n=2N$, and  observe that
$$ \frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2N}{4N}}  \leq \sup_{x\in (0,1)}\frac{1}{1+2Nx}<\frac{1}{2}$$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, it is not uniformly convergent

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to notice that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$x\mapsto\frac{1}{1+nx}$$

for $x\geq0$, is decreasing, and so, as this is a continuous function on $[0,1]$,

$$\sup_{x\in(0,1)}\frac{1}{1+nx}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}\frac{1}{1+nx}=1.$$

As $1\not\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ (obviously), the sequence does not converge uniformly on $(0,1)$.